# How to get the first value from an Array after split String in Data weave?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to compare the first value in the string array after split the string .
But my sub function throwing error saying it receiving an array , What i am doing wrong .

```
fun getErrorList() =
compareAddress(loanData.loan.propertyAddress,payload.propertyAddress)
fun compareAddress(loanpropertyAddress, inputPropertyAddress) =
if(null != loanpropertyAddress and null != inputPropertyAddress)
getAddr1 (loanpropertyAddress splitBy(" "))[0]
==
getAddr1 (inputPropertyAddress splitBy(" "))[0]
else
null

fun getAddr1(addr1) =
addr1 replace "#" with ("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are calling the getAddr1 function. In the DataWeave expression you provided, your passing to the getAddr1 function an array of strings instead of a string:

```
...
getAddr1(
    loadpropertyAddress splitBy(" ") // splitBy returns an array of strings
)[0] // here, you're trying to get the first element of the value returned by getAddr1
...
```

I'm assuming you are trying to compare the first part of loan and input property addresses after removing "#" characters. If my understanding is correct, then you can do the following changes to your function:

```
...
getAddr1(
    loadpropertyAddress splitBy(" ")[0] // get the first element of the string array returned by the splitBy function
) // removed array item selector ([0])
...
```

With that modification, your DataWeave expression should look like:

```
fun getErrorList() =
compareAddress(loanData.loan.propertyAddress,payload.propertyAddress)
fun compareAddress(loanpropertyAddress, inputPropertyAddress) =
if(null != loanpropertyAddress and null != inputPropertyAddress)
getAddr1 (loanpropertyAddress splitBy(" ")[0])
==
getAddr1 (inputPropertyAddress splitBy(" ")[0])
else
null

fun getAddr1(addr1) =
addr1 replace "#" with ("")
```